# why i the pointer is not a structure or union?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct m_tag {
    short m_tag_id;
    short m_tag_len;
    int   m_tag_cookie;
};
struct packet_tags {
    struct m_tag *slh_first;
}tags;

#define SFIRST(head) ((head).slh_first)
int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", SFIRST(&tags));
    return 0;
}
```

In function 'main':
error: request for member 'slh_first' in something not a structure or union

what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Because if you look at a sign that says "lake this way", the sign is not the lake?

Comment: Have you tried to access `slh_first` **without** using the macro? How would that look?

Comment: Your options are: `stuctPointer->structMember` or `structObject.structMember` but not `stuctPointer.structMember`

Comment: Btw, are you writing C or C++? You can only compile this small program with a single compiler at a time, after all. Please don't add tags just to attract views, that's an abuse of the system, and will be very much frowned upon by both the C and C++ community here.

Comment: Such macros can be useful in C, but should be avoided in C++, prefer inline (templated) functions instead.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access the `slh_first` member using `operator.` which requires an **instance** of `packet_tags` on the left side. But you are not passing an instance of `packet_tags` to `SFIRST()`, you are passing a **pointer** to a `packet_tags` instance. So, in order to access the member, you need to dereference the pointer to reach the instance. Calling `operator.` on a pointer is what the compiler is complaining about.

Change `SFIRST()` to this instead:

```
#define SFIRST(head) ((head)->slh_first)
```

Or, less preferred but just as valid:

```
#define SFIRST(head) ((*(head)).slh_first)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct m_tag {
    short m_tag_id;
    short m_tag_len;
    int   m_tag_cookie;
};
struct packet_tags {
    struct m_tag *slh_first;
}tags;

#define SFIRST(head) ((head)->slh_first)
int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", SFIRST(&tags));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Change your code to this" is not a useful SO answer. Why is the change required? What was the OP doing wrong? Look at the existing answer to see an example of how one should be answering questions here. Btw, it already suggested the fix you do here.

Comment: Also this is an nth duplicate.